# Multiregion/multilanguage website with Cloudflare and Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers, cloudflare, region

I want to build a site where (to start with) the domain and the text of the home changes depending on the visitor's country.

I would like to know if my logic/way is correct, or if there's a better way to do it, in order to use just 2 files (index.php and home.php)

So, in my index.php I detect the ip/country with Cloudflare

`($country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];`

Afterwards, I make a redirect towards the subdomain :

```
if ($country_code=="FR") {
        header('Location:https://fr'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].')
}
if ($country_code=="DE") {
        header('Location:https://de'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].')
}
ETC
```

Then I use nginx to catch those subdomains (that I set up first on Cloudflare) and I point all of them to the same home.php

So finally in my home.php I display the text/lang based on the country , but the visitor, depending on its country will be at fr.example.com , de.example.com , etc

Is this ok, or I should do it differently ?

Comment: What happens if someone from Germany visits: `https://fr.example.com/home.php`?

Comment: Thanks for the question! Didn't think about this possibility , but since I would still check in home.php for the country, to display the correct language, if I see that the subdomain and country don't match, I would ask to the visitor if he wants to change his country.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work, you just need to add "a no direct access" to those subdomains
"https://fr.example.com/"

```
if ($country_code=="FR") {
        header('Location:https://fr'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].')
}
if ($country_code=="DE") {
        header('Location:https://de'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].')
}
```